# JS - Remapping an Array and adding a parent element a child array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to figure out how to remap the below array to group the `variationOptions` under `variationName` (removing any duplicates) and add the `vendor_uLID` of the parent to the `variationOption` as a new element.

I've included both the input and output I am looking to get.

The script I've written so far groups the variations by name, however I can't seem to add the `vendor_uLID` to the `variationOption`.

How do I add the `vendor_uLID` each of the `variationOption`'s where its the parent of the `variationOption` in the inputArray?

JS Code:

```
company.productVariations.forEach(variation => {
    const variationIndex = currentOutput.findIndex(
      outputVariation =>
        variation.variationName === outputVariation.variationName
    )
    currentOutput.forEach(option => {
      option.variationOptions.forEach(op => {
        op['linkedVendors'] = []
        op.linkedVendors.push(company.vendor_uLID)
      })
    })
    if (variationIndex === -1) {
      currentOutput.push({
        variationName: variation.variationName,
        variationOptions: variation.variationOptions,
        record_uLID: variation.record_uLID,
      })
    } else {
      variation.variationOptions.forEach(variationOption => {
        if (
          !currentOutput[variationIndex].variationOptions.some(
            outputVariationOption =>
              variationOption.record_uLID === outputVariationOption.record_uLID
          )
        ) {
          currentOutput[variationIndex].variationOptions.push(variationOption)
        }
      })
    }
  })
  return currentOutput
}, [])
```

Input Array

```
var arrayIn = [
      {
        vendor_uLID: '5e793a0411d2bef2e375cd00',
        productVariations: [
          {
            variationName: 'Colour',
            variationOptions: [
              {
                name: 'Blue',
                record_uLID: '6afa239e-ce53-40eb-addc-836d8ecc0051',
              },
              {
                name: 'green',
                record_uLID: '66654830-6850-490a-8eaf-9d505e3e4672',
              },
            ],
          },
          {
            variationName: 'Pattern',
            variationOptions: [
              {
                name: 'Bold',
                record_uLID: '6afa239e-ce53-40eb-addc-836d8ecc0055',
              },
              {
                name: 'Spotted',
                record_uLID: '66654830-6850-490a-8eaf-9d505e3e4671',
              }
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        vendor_uLID: '5e7bb266071f9601b6ad8f4e',
        productVariations: [
          {
            variationName: 'Colour',
            variationOptions: [
              {
                name: 'Blue',
                record_uLID: '6afa239e-ce53-40eb-addc-836d8ecc0051',
              },
              {
                name: 'purple',
                record_uLID: '66654830-6850-490a-8eaf-9d505e3e4672',
              },
            ],
          },
          {
            variationName: 'Pattern',
            variationOptions: [
              {
                name: 'Bold',
                record_uLID: '6afa239e-ce53-40eb-addc-836d8ecc0055',
              },
              {
                name: 'Spotted',
                record_uLID: '66654830-6850-490a-8eaf-9d505e3e4671',
              }
            ],
          },
        ],
      }
    ]
```

Output Array

```
  [
      {
        "variationName": "Colour",
        "variationOptions": [
          {
            "name": "Blue",
            "record_uLID": "6afa239e-ce53-40eb-addc-836d8ecc0051",
            "linkedVendors": [
              "5e793a0411d2bef2e375cd00",
              "5e7bb266071f9601b6ad8f4e",
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "green",
            "record_uLID": "66654830-6850-490a-8eaf-9d505e3e4672",
            "linkedVendors": [
              "5e793a0411d2bef2e375cd00",
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "purple",
            "record_uLID": "66654830-6850-490a-8eaf-9d505e3e4675",
            "linkedVendors": [
              "5e7bb266071f9601b6ad8f4e",
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "variationName": "Pattern",
        "variationOptions": [
          {
            "name": "Bold",
            "record_uLID": "6afa239e-ce53-40eb-addc-836d8ecc0055",
            "linkedVendors": [
              "5e7bb266071f9601b6ad8f4e",
              "5e793a0411d2bef2e375cd00"
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "Spotted",
            "record_uLID": "66654830-6850-490a-8eaf-9d505e3e4671",
            "linkedVendors": [
              "5e793a0411d2bef2e375cd00",
              "5e7bb266071f9601b6ad8f4e"

            ]
          }
        ]
      }]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way, using reduce to create a nested object (`tempOutput`) and then convert that to your desired array of objects style with `Object.values()`:

```js
const tempOutput = arrayIn.reduce((aggObj,vendor) => {
  
  vendor.productVariations.forEach(vari => {
    if (!aggObj[vari.variationName]){
      aggObj[vari.variationName] = {variationName: vari.variationName, variationOptions: {}};
    }
    vari.variationOptions.forEach(opt => {
      const currOptions = aggObj[vari.variationName]['variationOptions']
      if (!currOptions[opt.name]){
        currOptions[opt.name] = opt;
        opt.linkedVendors = [vendor.vendor_uLID];
      }
      else {
        currOptions[opt.name].linkedVendors.push(vendor.vendor_uLID);
      }
    })
  })  
  return aggObj;
}, {});

const finalOutput = Object.values(tempOutput).map(vari => {
  vari.variationOptions = Object.values(vari.variationOptions);
  return vari;
});
console.log(finalOutput);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script id="initData">
const arrayIn = [
    {
      vendor_uLID: '5e793a0411d2bef2e375cd00',
      productVariations: [
        {
          variationName: 'Colour',
          variationOptions: [
            {
              name: 'Blue',
              record_uLID: '6afa239e-ce53-40eb-addc-836d8ecc0051',
            },
            {
              name: 'green',
              record_uLID: '66654830-6850-490a-8eaf-9d505e3e4672',
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          variationName: 'Pattern',
          variationOptions: [
            {
              name: 'Bold',
              record_uLID: '6afa239e-ce53-40eb-addc-836d8ecc0055',
            },
            {
              name: 'Spotted',
              record_uLID: '66654830-6850-490a-8eaf-9d505e3e4671',
            }
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      vendor_uLID: '5e7bb266071f9601b6ad8f4e',
      productVariations: [
        {
          variationName: 'Colour',
          variationOptions: [
            {
              name: 'Blue',
              record_uLID: '6afa239e-ce53-40eb-addc-836d8ecc0051',
            },
            {
              name: 'purple',
              record_uLID: '66654830-6850-490a-8eaf-9d505e3e4672',
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          variationName: 'Pattern',
          variationOptions: [
            {
              name: 'Bold',
              record_uLID: '6afa239e-ce53-40eb-addc-836d8ecc0055',
            },
            {
              name: 'Spotted',
              record_uLID: '66654830-6850-490a-8eaf-9d505e3e4671',
            }
          ],
        },
      ],
    }
];
</script>
```

Output:

```js
[
  {
    "variationName": "Colour",
    "variationOptions": [
      {
        "name": "Blue",
        "record_uLID": "6afa239e-ce53-40eb-addc-836d8ecc0051",
        "linkedVendors": [
          "5e793a0411d2bef2e375cd00",
          "5e7bb266071f9601b6ad8f4e"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "green",
        "record_uLID": "66654830-6850-490a-8eaf-9d505e3e4672",
        "linkedVendors": [
          "5e793a0411d2bef2e375cd00"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "purple",
        "record_uLID": "66654830-6850-490a-8eaf-9d505e3e4672",
        "linkedVendors": [
          "5e7bb266071f9601b6ad8f4e"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "variationName": "Pattern",
    "variationOptions": [
      {
        "name": "Bold",
        "record_uLID": "6afa239e-ce53-40eb-addc-836d8ecc0055",
        "linkedVendors": [
          "5e793a0411d2bef2e375cd00",
          "5e7bb266071f9601b6ad8f4e"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Spotted",
        "record_uLID": "66654830-6850-490a-8eaf-9d505e3e4671",
        "linkedVendors": [
          "5e793a0411d2bef2e375cd00",
          "5e7bb266071f9601b6ad8f4e"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: This is perfect.

Comment: Good to hear! :)